# Set initial value of zoom

Tags: javascript, charts

How can I set a init value for zoom in chartjs-plugin-zoom? I have this graph and I need that it show only 10 element and then user can scroll from left to right to show more data.

[image]

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551904/add-zoom-event-handler-to-charts-for-chartjs-with-chartjs-plugin-zoom) is probably what you searching for.

Comment: @AlexCode not, my issue is different. I don't need reset zoom, but show only one part of data

Comment: Then I think what you need is not a zoom but to show specific range of values.

Comment: @AlexCode Exactly

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. However, in contrary to you, I'm having realtime data and so I'm using chartjs-plugin-streaming; https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-streaming

If you use this plugin you can set your duration value in the options section. This worked for me:

```
function adaptZoom5min() {
    myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].realtime.duration = 300000;
    window.myChart.update();
}
```

In combination with this:

```
<button onclick="adaptZoom5min()">5min</button>
```

Hope this helps you as well (or others that have a similar problem)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of label you are displaying in your chart. For normal use case, showing number or string, you can include your min and max of your x-axis in options.scales.xAxes.ticks object.

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          padding: 20,
          min: 10,
          max: 30
        }
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
          borderDash: [4, 8],
          color: '#cdd6db'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

This is working well for me when I am using number or string for x-axis label. Hope that this helps you with your question. Cheers. :)